# In App billing on Amazon AppStore

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, amazon-appstore

Seeing as my country is not supported for Google Merchant account, I have to try and work on alternatives.

I could probably open a foreign bank account, have someone in a supported country create a dev and merchant account for me and then start with In App billing implementation for Google Play and hope Google doesn't ban me and remove my app from Store.

Or I could look into Amazon AppStore. I need someone to confirm some info for me:

1. Developer account is absolutely free - I can just register and
   upload my apps without any one-time of yearly fees

.
2. From what I can find, Amazon should support all countries for In-App billing?

Anyone has any experience with publishing Android apps with In-app billing to Amazon?